# Setting specular_intensity using Python, Material not updating

Tags: python, materials

I'm trying to change the *specular_intensity* setting using python. However, the setting isn't being set in Blender. It stays at the default 0.5. What am I doing wrong?

Docs:
https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.Material.html#bpy.types.Material.specular_intensity

I tried it two ways:

**1.**

```
mat = bpy.data.materials.new(name=f"material.001")
mat.use_nodes = True
print(mat.specular_intensity)
mat.specular_intensity = 0.0
bsdf = mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"]
texImage = mat.node_tree.nodes.new('ShaderNodeTexImage')
texImage.image = bpy.data.images.load(
    rf"C:\Users\me\image.png")
mat.node_tree.links.new(bsdf.inputs['Base Color'], texImage.outputs['Color'])

print(mat.specular_intensity)

# Assign it to object
if ob.data.materials:
    ob.data.materials[0] = mat
```

**Output:**
0.5,
0.0

Result:
The image is being displayed correctly, but the setting *Specular* stays at the default 0.5.

**2**

```
import bpy

ob = bpy.data.objects.get("object.001")
old_mat = ob.material_slots[0].material
new_mat = old_mat.copy()
new_mat.specular_intensity = 0.0

ob.material_slots[0].material = new_mat
```

Result:
*Specular* stays at 0.5

Comment: If you have a surface such as Principled BSDF, for me, using "mat.node_tree.nodes["Principled BSDF"].inputs["Specular"].default_value = 0" works

Comment: @AdamS yeah, that works perfectly - thank you!